# Pascal compilation error due to no Graphics unit

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am running into a problem with compiling a given source code in pascal, using the latest version of compiler. It whines that it can't find the Graphics unit used by the [program]. As it is my first hours with Pascal so far I just got to download the Graphics32 and putted it into the FPC\2.6.2\units\i386-win32.

Here's the screenshot of the problem, I would appreciate any help for a total newbie.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit graphics (the Delphi unit) is VCL, and thus part of Lazarus, not FPC.

Rule of thumb is that everything "forms" and below is Lazarus.